# How to know if a python script is running with admin permissions in windows?

Tags: python

I want to check if a python script is running with admin permissions on windows, without using the ctypes module. It is important for me not to use ctypes for some reasons.

I have looked with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: any reasons why you wish not to use ctypes?

Comment: yes. But they are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening a file that requires admin permissions, here's a sketch of how you might do that:

```
file_requiring_admin_permissions = "C:/Windows/WindowsUpdate.log"
try:
    with open(file_requiring_admin_permissions, 'w'):
        print("Opened OK")
except PermissionError:
    print("Permission error, not admin")
except IOError as e:
    import os
    print(os.strerror(e.errno))
```

Comment: Is there a way without try except?

Comment: Using exception handling *is* the pythonic way to do this.

Comment: True. But is there a way without try except?

Comment: @avichoen: nope, otherwise your application will halt on the Exception. May I know why you want to do it without `try/except`?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the pywin tool set, the function `win32.shell.IsUserAnAdmin()` can be used to see if you a a member of the administrators group.